# Query about Schengen visa application from Saudi Arabia

Tags: schengen, schengen-visas

Me, my wife and our son are residents  (Iqama holders) in Saudi Arabia. My mother-in-law has a multiple exit re-entry visa with 2 years validity and stays with us most days of the year. if we need to apply for Schengen visa, can my mother-in-law also apply from Saudi Arabia? Or does she have to apply for the visa from our home country (India). She will be staying almost around till the time of our travel dates to Europe and hence wont have sufficient time to go back to home country to get Schengen visa stamped.

Kindly reply so that we can plan our travel accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Generally, she has to apply from her **place of residence**. There are exceptions, however, and if she will not return to India for several months before the trip she can apply from Saudi Arabia. She would have to explain why she qualifies for that exception.